# What are the flat space requirements for a wormhole?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, wormholes

From my understanding, wormholes generally have flat space requirements. Regions around the wormhole where space cannot be significantly distorted. For this reason, Wormholes with very high flat space requirements may have to be laid to rest outside a solar system to prevent destabilisation. 
 
My question is; **What are the flat space requirements for a Wormhole** *(any metric is fine)*. 
 
***(A Morris-Thorne based metric / an Ellis metric would be preferred if possible.)*** 
 
I'm aware this may not be extremely simple, or may vary based on size / density / e.g. However, literally any answer that could potentially get me closer to understanding the requirements, be it an equation or some theoretical physicist's quote is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "flat space requirements for a wormhole"?

Comment: Apologies, I realise that might not be too understandable. Will edit now.

Comment: You are using non-standard terms so I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Apologies. I have no clue what to call it. This is the only term I have heard used to refer to it. I've effectively (but badly) trying to ask, what are the requirements of a wormhole, in terms of flat (lacking significant gravitational bodies) space.